# I tried many way to get rid off 415 unsupported media type error. Still getting the same error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

This is the AJAX request

```
$('#save').on('click',function(){
  alert("test");
  var data = $('form').serialize();
  console.log("data"+data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveExpenses",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      alert("Success");
    }
  });
});
```

**Controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveExpenses",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveExpense(@RequestBody ExpensesSummary expenses, HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session){
    System.out.println("first name"+expenses.getFirstName());
    String message = homeBankingDao.expenseSummary(expenses);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("message",message);
    return null;        
}
```

**Console log**
datafirstName=yuvanath&lastName=M&email=yuva92m%40gmail.com&typeOfExpense=sfsdf&date=&amount=&mode=
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/HomeBankingSystem/saveExpenses 400 (Bad Request)

If I remove @requestbody annotation it throwing 400 bad request error.

Please help me with this

Comment: I don't see you setting a content-type anywhere in your request.

Comment: but by default it will take dataType : "html",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", ??

Comment: anyway if i add content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded..then also same error @chrylis

Comment: What happens if you change the `@RequestBody` to `@ModelAttribute`?

Comment: 400 bad request error @chrylis

Comment: Post code of your html form.

Comment: And post the log output from the server. It's usually fairly detailed.

Comment: data: firstName=yuvanath&lastName=M&email=yuva92m%40gmail.com&typeOfExpense=sfsdf&date=&amount=&mode=
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/HomeBankingSystem/saveExpenses 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: $('form').serialize() maybe you need to serialize object by JSON.stringfy() at least jackson has to convert parameters to entity